# How do I know Rails has loaded/cached an Activerecord class attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord

Suppose I have a ActiveRecord class "User".

I realize the first time I use it via User.new, Rails makes a call to the database to get the actual attributes of User from the users table. Subsequent times it is cached, and doesn't require a database call.

This is fine.. and straightforward in a single thread.

Suppose I have multiple threads running in a single process. The first thread that calls User.new (or anything that involves User, such as finding one), will lookup the attributes in the database. The subsequent ones will have them cached.

**Is there a way to check to see if the ActiveRecord attributes are cached or not?**

I don't want to have to always check out a database connection via ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection when I call User.new, when I don't plan on using the database connection - Yes not even saving it.

```
u = nil

ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do # I don't want to checkout a conn if User attributes are cached.
   u = User.new
end

#manipulation of u. but u.save NEVER ever gets called.
```

I won't fully explained my entire reasoning, but doing so would detract people from answering because in a word: it's complicated. Here's an article if interested though that is similar to my problem: https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/activerecord-concurrency-in-rails4-avoid-leaked-connections/ I basically do NOT want to checkout a database connection if possible, but still want to call User.new to manipulate with it but NOT save it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. The actual schema cache can be found under [`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_cache`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb), but the act of calling `connection` causes it to be opened. If `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?` if false you can assume there is no schema cache, and if it is true you would have to inspect the `@columns` ivar of your `schema_cache` instance.

This is hacky because the Active Record pattern assumes that objects are connected to a datasource. If you need domain objects that are independent of your DB, I would recommend writing them as POROs using [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) + `ActiveModel::Validation`, or [dry-struct](http://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-struct/) etc.